# GETDATE() by utc + 2 SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to getDate by utc??? Right now i have i time diff in -2 hours. Current UTC0. I need getDate() utc+2

```
select *
from dbo.KEY_SalesToStudents
where SaleDate < getDate()
    and SaleDate > DateADD(mi, - 5, getDate())
order by SaleDAte
```

Comment: which RDBMS ?? ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`GetUTCDate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx)?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 5):

Sql server provides multiple built in functions to get the current local date and the current UTC date.

To get the UTC date and time you can use [`GETUTCDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx), that will return a `DateTime` data type, or [`SYSUTCDATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx), that will return a `datetime2(7)` data type.

Example:

```
SELECT  GETDATE() As [GETDATE()],
        GETUTCDATE() As [GETUTCDATE()], 
        SYSUTCDATETIME() As [SYSUTCDATETIME()];
```

Results (on my local pc):

```
GETDATE()                   GETUTCDATE()                SYSUTCDATETIME()
2017-03-19 14:10:20.320     2017-03-19 12:10:20.317     2017-03-19 12:10:20.5482578
```

[You can play with it yourself on rextester](http://rextester.com/CNBDC20787)

Comment: but my problem is that date is not UTC + 2 time zone. How to explain sql which time zone should be compared.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. I've shown you two ways of getting UTC datetime values in sql server. Now that you know how to get local time as well as utc time, what's the problem?

Comment: my problem is that my utc time is not correct. i am trying to get data by GETUTCDATE(), but i taken date 3 hours ago. Id u want me to explain deeply, we can to in skype conversation and discuss it

Answer (score 1):

As long as the server's date and time are set correctly you could use something like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, +2, GETUTCDATE()) AS [UTC +2 Hours]
```

Answer (score 0):

GetDate() in SqlServer seem to respect the time zone that you have configured in Linux.
You can list the valid timezones and set time zone like this:

```
einska@sql02:~$ timedatectl list-timezones 
einska@sql02:~$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone "Europe/Oslo"
```